# How to pass a value from a delegate to another one in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass the url in documentPicker to previewController. Since all of them are delegates, I can't simply return because that will violate the protocol. How to pass the data from a view to another view? Thanks!

```
func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController!, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
    //var doc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)
    return doc
}
func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
    println("\(url)")
    var quickView = QLPreviewController()
    quickView.dataSource = self
    presentViewController(quickView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~Update~~~~~~~~~6.2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Now I follow the idea of the answer as follow

```
func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
    println("\(url)")

    var a: String = "\(url)"

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(a, forKey: "URL")

    var quickView = QLPreviewController()


    quickView.dataSource = self

    presentViewController(quickView, animated: true, completion: nil)




}
```

and

```
func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController!, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem!{

    var  url = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("URL") as! String
    var doc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url)
    return doc
}
```

By doing so I avoid the format issue of NSUserDefaults, but the program still break at doc (Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1)

For example, when run it and select a file, the url is
    file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DEE5190D-6E3F-4400-8866-4668B830C588/tmp/DocumentPickerIncoming/Experiment_7.PDF

and the doc is : Optional(file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DEE5190D-6E3F-4400-8866-4668B830C588/tmp/DocumentPickerIncoming/Experiment_7.PDF -- file:///)

they are the same. Why the app break?

Comment: Not so sure about the `computer-science` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can store your Url in `NSUserDefaults`. And use it whenever you want. You can store text in `NSUserDefaults`

```
func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
println("\(url)")

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(url, forKey: "URL")

var quickView = QLPreviewController()


quickView.dataSource = self

presentViewController(quickView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

and retrieve it in

```
func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController!, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {

var doc = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("URL") as! NSUrl
return doc
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much first!
But then I got this error: Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFURL')

Attempt to set a non-property-list object file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E35D89E8-3C43-47CC-8F69-265AAAC06F21/tmp/DocumentPickerIncoming/Experiment_7.PDF as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key URL

it's like they don't like the URL type. How to fix that?
Thank you!

Comment: I would like to. But my reputation is too low to do so. Once I get enough reputation, I will do that.